# How did I vote 41 times today?

Tags: support, voting, private-beta

According to my [profile on this private beta](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users/83/monica-cellio), I have voted 41 times today.  The site is only two days old, so this isn't some accidental mis-allocation of previous votes -- 80 should be the maximum number of votes for the life of the account, but I have apparently voted 81 times.  I wasn't paying close attention, but nothing stands out in my memory, like odd behavior when casting votes.

[image: screen shot]

How is this possible?

Comment: Are there posts on which you voted that are deleted now?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's possible; how would I find out?  My "votes" tab shows 81 entries, I can't see deleted posts, and I'm not motivated to click through up to 81 entries to see if I get a 404.  (Are votes "refunded" on deletion, then?  I didn't know that.  I mean, I know that rep effects are cancelled, but I thought 40 votes/day meant the vote count couldn't go up by more than 40.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio The 'votes' tab does not include votes on deleted posts (same for the "N Votes Cast" on the profile page summary). It might be caching that makes that it still shows 81 votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tally will include *any* votes you cast that day.

However, the daily cap only applies to the votes in effect. That is, if you voted on a post that has since been deleted (and the votes are refunded) you have still *cast* those votes, but you also got them back, leading to this discrepancy.